# MSVC ignores [[maybe_unused]] for functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, visual-studio-2019

MSVC generates a warning for the following snippet of code:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    enum class Bar {
      SomeValue,
    };
};

[[maybe_unused]]
static const char* toString(Foo::Bar value) {
  switch (value) {
    case Foo::Bar::SomeValue:
      return "SomeValue";
  }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G3pCAv

My reading of cppreference on this would indicate this should work. Is MSVC not conforming when it comes to the [[maybe_unused]] attribute on functions (or at least static ones)?

Comment: I don't understand. The warning seems to have nothing to do with `[[maybe_unused]]`.

Comment: Are you using the `/std:c++17` switch in your project? Are you using a VS2017 version less than 15.3?

Comment: What warning do you get? That should be included in the question, not via a link.

Comment: I posted the link to god bolt. Try it out for yourself

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes?view=msvc-160), `[[maybe_unused]]` should work in this case. I would report the issue to M$FT.

Comment: @rustyx It appears that this issue was already reported more than 2 years ago https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-attribute-maybe-unused-is-ignored-for-static-fun/244236

Answer (score 1):

> Is MSVC not conforming

The standard merely recommends that entities marked as maybe_unused should not be warned about if not used. As such, warning that they are not used is against that recommendation, but still technically conforming.